# Preserve the default value of hidden radio button based on check box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, radio-button, checkboxlist

I am using a list of check boxes (dynamically generated) with coressponding hidden radio buttons. By clicking on a check box its corresponding radio button (with value "YES" and "No") become visible having selected default value as "Yes". If I change the value of radio box as "NO" and desselect the check box, corresponding radio box becomes hidden again. On selecting the same check box again, its corresponding radio box appears but with value as "NO" (as selected before making it hidden). I want it to come with defult value "YES" . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just update radio button value before making it visible. You can use

```
 $("#radioButtonId").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: @user3148416:you need to call the above code when you uncheck the any of checkbox, so that you can set the corresponding raio button to true(using above code) and hide it(which your doing it already)

Comment: M using an array of radio buttons in jsp.. so passed the id of radio button using loop in <% %>

Comment: @user3148416 My code will not work as-it-as. You need to update the jQuery selector and place the code in appropriate method